# Como acessar pastas em rede externa com c# asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Quando eu tento ler arquivos em uma outra rede(que exige autenticação), ocorre o erro abaixo. O mesmo problema eu também tenho quando tento acessar pastas protegidas.

Alguém sabe como faço para resolver isso ?

```
DirectoryInfo dirE = new DirectoryInfo(@"\\\\123.45.6.78\dados\Chapolin");
FileInfo[] filesE = dirE.GetFiles("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

> Additional information: Falha de logon: nome de usuário desconhecido
>   ou senha incorreta.

Comment: O usuário logado tem acesso a estas pastas?

Comment: Quando acessa direto pelo explorer a mesma mensagem é exibida? E outras pastas na rede, mesmo problema?

Comment: Veja: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5433570/access-a-remote-directory-from-c-sharp

Answer (score 3):

Bom, eu vi uma solução aqui (em inglês):

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ba0c7204-f102-4218-a503-1f4a304aa633/logon-failure-unknown-user-name-or-bad-password?forum=winformssetup

Basicamente, mude o caminho do arquivo pra esse padrão:

```
\\IPdoServidor\Pasta\documento.txt@usuárioComPermissão,SenhaDoUsuário
```

Veja se resolve seu problema